# Full page (no WP admin menus and options) admin theme options

Tags: themes, options

I'd like to drag and drop functionality into one of the admin pages and I've been wondering about the best way to implement it: an iframe or something else?

What I'd like is: Once the use choose the theme, it'll be redirected to the page (under one of the admin menus) which will have a link that would launch the drag and drop options in a full page (without the admin menu on the left side).

Like I said, I've been thinking about an iframe, but I'm not it'd be the best solution.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might find [this](http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/) to be an interesting read.

Comment: It does seems interesting, but what I meant was not fully full screen. I want to keep the browser window. I just don't want the wordpress admin menu items... Thanks for the tip anyway. It might be useful in the next project.

Answer (score 0):

From what I remember and quick look at code output of administration menu is hardcoded into `menu-header.php`, which in turn is hardcoded into `admin-header.php`. In other words not something you can get rid of easily and painlessly.

Note that admin menu can be collapsed to quite thin toolbar, so if your main need is to recover that space then easier and less confusing to user might be to collapse it by code (would probably need a bit of JavaScript, not my area), rather than remove it completely.

Comment: Ok, it seems getting rid of the admin menu might not be a good idea, but what about a page redirect using javascript? For instance, I could use `onclick="window.location.href = http://localhost:8888/wordpress/my_page_here"` to redirect the user to a custom page, however how could I include this page into my theme (either built in or self-created upon activating the theme)?